Quantum probabilistic method?
The probabilistic method uses arguments from probability to prove deterministic statements. This has been applied to diverse fields such as combinatorics, topology and number theory. In this method, you constructs a random variable based on the theorem that you want to prove. Using probabilistic arguments, you then show that the random variable has certain properties. From this the deterministic theorem follows.
I wonder if there is also a ‘quantum probabilistic method’. This would mean that you construct a (theoretical) quantum system based on a mathematical theorem that you want to prove. Then you prove that the quantum system must have certain properties, from which the mathematical theorem follows.

I guess you could argue that the recent proof that Connes' embedding conjecture is false uses such a method.

Here is the arXiv preprint of the paper that @Alubeixu referenced: https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.04383. I think this is a really good example for your question.

The Hilbert-Polya approach to the Riemann hypothesis follows this path, by attempting to relate the zeroes of the Riemann zeta function to a quantum mechanical scattering problem. The probability distribution of the energy levels of a chaotic quantum system with broken time-reversal symmetry is conjectured to describe the local statistics of the zeta-function zeroes, see for example Physics of the Riemann Hypothesis.

Quantum algorithms provide a different area of quantum physics that is used to prove deterministic mathematical theorems. Drucker and De Wolf given an overview in Quantum Proofs for Classical Theorems. An example, is a proof of Jackson's inequality by means of a quantum probabilistic approach to polynomial approximation.

It seems that this has not led to a proof. Are there also examples where applying quantum mechanics actually proved a theorem?

I have added one such example (and a reference which contains several more).
